# Goroutines not Using Max CPU and Cores

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm realizing my very first `Golang` application and I'm having some issues on using `MAX CPU & Cores` when using `GoRoutines` and I don't really know why.

When using a tool such as `htop`, `CPU` isn't used at its max power and only `1..4 threads` are active at time. Also, all `cores` are active but they are around `25%-40%` utilization.

I used:

```
func MaxParallelism() int {
    maxProcs := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
    numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    if maxProcs < numCPU {
        return maxProcs
    }
    return numCPU
}
```

In order to get the number of `goroutines` to be instantiated.

Here's How I set up the application:

```
//Common Channel for the goroutines
tasks := make(chan *exec.Cmd, 64)

    //Spawning Max Cores Number goroutines (8)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    cores := MaxParallelism()
    for i := 0; i < cores; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(num int, w *sync.WaitGroup) {
            defer w.Done()
            var (
                out []byte
                err error
            )
            for cmd := range tasks {
                out, err = cmd.Output()
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Can't get stdout:", err)
                }
                . . .
            }
        }(i, &wg)
    }

    //Generate Tasks
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
      tasks <- exec.Command(cmd1, args...)
      tasks <- exec.Command(cmd2, args...)
    }

close(tasks)
// wait for the workers to finish
wg.Wait()
```

I share two screenshots of `htop` while executing the application

[image]
[image]

I don't know If it May help but I'm launching it through `Intellij Idea`.

**How do I use Max CPU properly and Cores?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it's not using enough CPU cores? What behavior do you expect, and what behavior do you observe?

Comment: I share a screen of `htop` while executing the application so you'll understand it. Basically, there's only `1 thread active` at a time and all cores are used around 25%.

Comment: You say you're spawning 4 goroutines. How do you know you're getting 4?

Comment: That's an error, I spawn 8 of them using the for and giving it Max Cores.

Comment: Your goroutines are just spawning other processes. Your Go process isn't going any real work, so why would it use any CPU time?

Comment: How do you know you're getting 8 goroutines, then? Did you remember to set GOMAXPROCS to at least 8?

Comment: @user2357112 Cores is 8 from `cores := MaxParallelism()` or do you think I did it wrong?

Comment: And what are your goroutines doing that you think they should use more than one CPU? It looks to me like they're executing external commands, which means the goroutines will run for microseconds at most, then do nothing waiting for the command to return. But you haven't shown us enough to really know for sure.

Comment: You are right, they have to execute 2 different external commands and write their result in a file. I did not share the code because I think I'm doing something wrong on the piece of code I put above. I would just like to use my resources at 100%. Do you think that the fact that those external commands are Pretty slow lead to an underutilization of resources because goroutines are waiting for response?

Comment: @AndreaM16: running external commands and writing the output to a file takes almost no resources. You're program isn't going to use 100% of your CPUs, because it's not doing anything. If the external commands are doing the work, they are what will be using the CPU time.

Comment: I noticed that `CPU` and `Core` utilization grows when generating lots of tasks, so, basically, `Go` understands by its own when and how using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goroutines and threads are not the same. Ergo you should not expect any CPU affinity. See more for details here http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/30/goroutines-vs-threads/.

> Here are some of the advantages of Goroutines over threads:
>
> - You can run more goroutines on a typical system than you can threads.
> - Goroutines have growable segmented stacks.
> - Goroutines have a faster startup time than threads.
> - Goroutines come with built-in primitives to communicate safely between themselves (channels).
> - Goroutines allow you to avoid having to resort to mutex locking when sharing data structures.
> - Goroutines are multiplexed onto a small number of OS threads, rather than a 1:1 mapping.
> - You can write massively concurrent servers without having to resort to evented programming.

EDIT:
Answer to your question in the comments. There is no definitive answer. As others mentioned, it depends on what your code does. You may never end up using 100% CPU if you, for example, do I/O, which is slow. So no matter how many routines you start, I/O is slow. Contrarily, if your goroutine has a very tight loop doing just some computation then it's likely that 8 goroutines will consume your 8 CPUs completely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I said I'm Pretty new to Go in general and I don't know many things since I'm using it from few days. So, basically, Hoe many goroutines should I instantiate with 4 cores and a solid I7? I would just like to use my resources at their maximum possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

After reading around, getting some hints and trying some stuff, it came out that the code was written just fine and there were not real problems caused by it.

Essentially, `Go` scales pretty good and, the more `tasks` you generate, the more `CPU` resources are used.

For instance, setting an higher range on the `for`, e.g. `1.000.000`, makes `Go` use all the `cores` available at `~55%` of their possibilities.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's a code which will likely max out your CPU. I run concurrently 256 routines (#1 routine + those spawned within the for loop).

```golang
package main

func main() {
  for i := 0; i < 255; i++ {
    go func() {
      for {}
    }()
  }

  for {}
}
```

[image]

If you execute only one routine (the #1 routine), you'll see only one CPU core is used:

```golang
package main

func main() {
  for {}
}
```

[image]

If you execute 2 routines (the #1 routine + the spawned one), you'll see 2 CPU cores are used:

```golang
package main

func main() {
  go func(){
    for {}
  }()

  for {}
}
```

[image]

Go scales routines across CPU cores automatically.

[Worth noting that go routines are not the same as functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53389196/8555937)