# Is the main function run a goroutine?

Tags: go

Is the `main()` function a goroutine?  For example, I've seen a crash stack trace like the below, which makes me ask:

```
goroutine 1 [running]: main.binarySearch(0x0, 0x61, 0x43,
0xc420043e70, 0x19, 0x19, 0x10)
     /home/---/go/src/github.com/----/sumnum.go:22 +0x80 main.main()
     /home/---/go/src/github.com/---/sumnum.go:13 +0xc1 exit status 2
```

Comment: @Volker Well I'm trying to learn a golang and by mistake this error is generated and I see in the error  `panic: runtime error: index out of range` so then this question comes in my mind

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the main function runs as a goroutine (the main one).

According to https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

> A goroutine is a lightweight thread managed by the Go runtime.
> `go f(x, y, z)`
> starts a new goroutine running `f(x, y, z)` The evaluation of f, x, y, and z happens in the **current goroutine** and the execution of `f` happens in the new goroutine.
> Goroutines run in the same address space, so access to shared memory must be synchronized. The sync package provides useful primitives, although you won't need them much in Go as there are other primitives.

So according to this official document the `main` is the **current goroutine**.
To be precise (literally) we could address the `main` as the current goroutine, so simply speaking it is a goroutine. (Note: Literally speaking the `main()` is a function which could run as a goroutine.)

---

Now let's **count** the number of goroutines using `runtime.NumGoroutine()`:

As an example let's run 3 goroutines. Try it [online](https://play.golang.org/p/CT3vL4i0cGl):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 3
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
func init() {
    go main()
    go main()
}
```

---

Here the **current goroutine** runs the **new goroutine**, so here we have **more than one goroutine**, which executes `main()` again. Try it [online](https://play.golang.org/p/R9TonRYEniB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 1 2 3 4
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&i) <= 0 {
        return
    }
    atomic.AddInt32(&i, -1)
    go main()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}

var i int32 = 3
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Here we have one `main` goroutine plus 3 user called `main` goroutines, so total number of goroutines are 4 here.

---

Let's calculate factorial using `main()` (**one goroutine** - no synchronization needed). Try it [online](https://play.golang.org/p/7YK9o_u72bM):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    if f <= 0 {
        fmt.Println(acc)
        return
    }
    acc *= f
    f--
    main()
}

var f = 5
var acc = 1
```

Output:

```
120
```

Note: The codes above are just for clearly showing my viewpoints and is not good for production use (Using global variables should not be the first choice).

Comment: what is the meaning of "The evaluation happens in the current goroutine and the execution happens in the new goroutine."

Comment: It means will **run** if it is a function or calculated (if needed). See examples for [go-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678876/why-input-text-is-evaluated-in-the-main-goroutine/58679714#58679714)  and [defer-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660508/how-defer-keyword-works-in-go/58661114#58661114) for example `go have()(fun("with Go."))` the `have()` will run i.e. evaluated. [try it here](https://play.golang.org/p/2-13guGXeZj)

Answer (score 13):

> Is the main function a goroutine?

No.

The main function is a function.

In contrast,

> A *goroutine* is a lightweight thread of execution. ([source](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines)).

So goroutines execute functions, but goroutines are not functions, and there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between goroutines and functions.

However...

The `main()` function is executed in the first (and at startup, only) goroutine, `goroutine #1`.

But as soon as that function calls another function, then the main goroutine is no longer executing the main function, and is instead executing some other function.

So it's clear that a goroutine and a function are entirely different entities.

*Do not conflate goroutines with functions!!*

Functions and goroutines are entirely different concepts.  And thinking of them as the same thing will lead to countless confusion and problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Main func can spawn other goroutines, but "main" itself is one groutine.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
)

func main() {
        // Goroutine num includes main processing
        fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 1

        // Spawn two goroutines
        go func() {}()
        go func() {}()

        // Total three goroutines run
        fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 3
}
```