# Best way to pass context.Context to a closure executed in a separate goroutine

Tags: go, closures, goroutine

What is best way to pass `context.Context` to closure to be executed in a separate goroutine?

Since I'm not mutating `context.Context` inside the closure, I assume both options are valid. 2nd option can save me tiny bit of memory by not copying the interface.

1) pass as an argument

```golang
func run(ctx context.Context) {
  for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
    go func(id int, ictx context.Context) {
      for {
        select {
          case <- ictx.Done():
            return
          default:
            // do something
        }
      }
    }(i, ctx)
  }
}
```

2) expose outer context variable

```golang
func run(ctx context.Context) {
  for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
    go func(id int) {
      for {
        select {
          case <- ctx.Done():
            return
          default:
            // do something
        }
      }
    }(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 looks good. the context should be the same in both options so using the outer func seems fine

Comment: In the first example: Context should be the first argument by convention. Aside from that: It does not matter.

Answer (score 5):

Both should be fine. The key to remember is that contexts are immutable. This means there's no risk of a race condition where some other goroutine is updating the context as you're trying to read it, so you don't need to worry about the normal synchronization methods.

So in short, nothing special is needed so #2 is just fine. Since #1 isn't actually executing a closure, it's ideal in situations where you want to execute a named function, which takes a context argument

---

**Note on terminology:** Your original question (which I edited for clarity) asked about executing "a goroutine in a closure." Technically speaking, this is non-sense. But it's a common confusion. Goroutines are light-weight threads of execution. Functions are bits of code. They are not the same thing, so referring to functions or closures as goroutines doesn't really make sense. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53389196/13860) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr Unless you have an unusually large context constructed using WithValue, it won't make a large difference in either case.

Example 1) the anonymous function called as a go routine is not a closure because you pass both i and ctx as arguments (closures, by definition, contain outside variables or state without passing them in as arguments)

Example 2) the anonymous function called as a go routine is a closure because it uses variables from the outer function "run()" without passing them in as parameters/arguments

Passing non-pointer parameters makes a copy of the variable and the original (outer) won't be modified by inner changes. Using a closure allows the outer variable (state) to be changed by inner edits. Contexts are immutable so it doesn't matter whether you access them using a closure or passing them as parameters in terms of mutability. The difference is whether you will have the additional processing associated with copying the context variable as a result of passing as a parameter/argument.