# How defer keyword works in Go

Tags: go

Having an issue where the user is prompt to enter an age for the ticket price, but `if` statement only prints 9.99 when the entered age is above 13:

Tried `:=`, and `fmt.Println(ticketPrice == 19.99)`.
If anyone has another suggestion, let me know.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var age int
    var ticketprice float64

    defer fmt.Println("Your age is:", getAge(age)) // calls getAge
    defer fmt.Println("Your ticket price is:", printTicket(age,
        ticketprice)) // calls printTicket
}
func printTicket(age int, ticketPrice float64) float64 {
    if age <= 13 {
        ticketPrice = 9.99 // only calls 9.99, not anything else
    } else if age > 13 && age < 65 {
        ticketPrice = 19.99 // not being called?
    } else if age >= 65 {
        ticketPrice = 12.99 // not being called?
    }
    return ticketPrice // returns ticket price
} // Whole function is not being used for some reason. Only returns 9.99, nothing else

func getAge(age int) int {
    fmt.Println("What is your age?")
    fmt.Scan(&age)
    for age < 0 || age > 100 {
        fmt.Println("That cannot be, please enter your age again")
        fmt.Scan(&age)
    }
    return age
}

func getName(name string) string {
    fmt.Println("What is your name?")
    fmt.Scan(&name)
    return name
}
```

Comment: `age` is never being set, so you're always passing an age of `0`, which is obviously less than 13.

Comment: I know age isn't being set, because stack only let me list part of my code. This is the full version. package main
import "fmt"

func getName(name string) string {
  fmt.Println("What is your name?")
  fmt.Scan(&name)
  return name
}

func getAge(age int) int {
  fmt.Println("What is your age?")
  fmt.Scan(&age)

   for age < 0 || age > 100 {
    fmt.Println("That cannot be, please enter your age again")
    fmt.Scan(&age)
  }
  return age
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Defer_statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the **function value** and **parameters** to the call are [evaluated as usual](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the reverse order they were deferred. That is, if the surrounding function returns through an explicit return statement, deferred functions are executed after any result parameters are set by that return statement but before the function returns to its caller. If a deferred function value evaluates to nil, execution panics when the function is invoked, not when the "defer" statement is executed.

Also, see an [example for the `go` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679714/8208215)

---

To understand the evaluation order, let's try this:

```
defer having()(fun("with Go."))
```

Let's run [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2OJyfNaiQkg) and read the code comments for the evaluation order:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer having()(fun("with Go."))
    fmt.Print("some ") // evaluation order: 3
}
func having() func(string) {
    fmt.Print("Go ") // evaluation order: 1
    return funWithGo
}
func fun(msg string) string {
    fmt.Print("have ") // evaluation order: 2
    return msg
}
func funWithGo(msg string) {
    fmt.Println("fun", msg) // evaluation order: 4
}
```

Output:

```
Go have some fun with Go.
```

[This](https://play.golang.org/p/B01yqsg2P53) is even more beautiful, with the same result, just replace all functions with anonymous functions:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() func(string) {
        fmt.Print("Go ") // evaluation order: 1
        return func(msg string) {
            fmt.Println("fun", msg) // evaluation order: 4
        }
    }()(func(msg string) string {
        fmt.Print("have ") // evaluation order: 2
        return msg
    }("with Go."))
    fmt.Print("some ") // evaluation order: 3
}
```

---

I hope this helps you to understand how the `defer` works:
A [working](https://play.golang.org/p/yTi-OqLd0sa) version of your code with enough documentation inside (Note `defer` parameters evaluated first in place and call to `fmt.Println` will be deferred to function return in reverse order):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printTicket(age int) float64 {
    fmt.Println("...order is 2...")
    switch {
    case age <= 13:
        return 9.99
    case age > 13 && age < 65:
        return 19.99
    default:
        return 12.99
    }
}

func main() {
    age := 999
    defer fmt.Println("...order is 4...Your age is:", getAge(&age))
    defer fmt.Println("...order is 3...Your ticket price is:", printTicket(age))
}

func getAge(age *int) int {
    fmt.Println("...order is 1...")
    fmt.Print("Enter age=")
    fmt.Scanln(age)
    return *age
}
```

Output:

```
...order is 1...
Enter age=999
...order is 2...
...order is 3...Your ticket price is: 12.99
...order is 4...Your age is: 999
```