# why input.Text() is evaluated in the main goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

In chapter 8 of [*The Go Programming Language*](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=SJHvCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT296&lpg=PT296&dq=input.Text()+is+evaluated+in+the+main+goroutine&source=bl&ots=qzkHFYgXuf&sig=ACfU3U2KCRpP3d2H-kX3bek5D4juin1aPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje8K2v3c3lAhU0zIsBHbfhCdkQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=input.Text()%20is%20evaluated%20in%20the%20main%20goroutine&f=false), there is a description to the concurrency echo server as below:

> The arguments to the function started by go are evaluated when the go statement itself is executed; thus input.Text() is evaluated in the main goroutine.

I don't understand this. Why the `input.Text()` is evaluated at the main goroutine? Shouldn't it be in the go echo() goroutine?

```golang
// Copyright © 2016 Alan A. A. Donovan & Brian W. Kernighan.
// License: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/

// See page 224.

// Reverb2 is a TCP server that simulates an echo.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func echo(c net.Conn, shout string, delay time.Duration) {
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToUpper(shout))
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", shout)
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToLower(shout))
}

//!+
func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    for input.Scan() {
        go echo(c, input.Text(), 1*time.Second)
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    c.Close()
}

//!-

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err) // e.g., connection aborted
            continue
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

code is here: https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/reverb2/reverb.go

Comment: Because the language spec says so.

Comment: All arguments are evaluated at the time the `go` keyword is encountered, then the goroutine starts with these calculated values. If you don't want this, you'll need to start a `func` that calculates these values, like this: `go func() { yourFuncWithArgs(arg1.Text(), arg2) }()`; however, that often doesn't make sense. The same behaviour is also valid for `defer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `go` keyword works in Go, see
[Go_statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements):

> The **function value** and **parameters** are [evaluated as usual](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) in the calling goroutine, but unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the function begins executing independently in a new goroutine. When the function terminates, its goroutine also terminates. If the function has any return values, they are discarded when the function completes.

---

The **function value** and **parameters** are **evaluated** in place with the `go` keyword (same for the `defer` keyword see an [example for `defer` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661114/8208215)).

---

To understand the evaluation order, let's try this:

```
go have()(fun("with Go."))
```

Let's run [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2-13guGXeZj) and read the code comments for the evaluation order:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    go have()(fun("with Go."))

    fmt.Print("some ") // evaluation order: ~ 3
    wg.Wait()
}

func have() func(string) {
    fmt.Print("Go ") // evaluation order: 1
    return funWithGo
}

func fun(msg string) string {
    fmt.Print("have ") // evaluation order: 2
    return msg
}

func funWithGo(msg string) {
    fmt.Println("fun", msg) // evaluation order: 4
    wg.Done()
}

func init() {
    wg.Add(1)
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

Output:

```
Go have some fun with Go.
```

**Explanation** `go have()(fun("with Go."))`:
First in place evaluation takes place here:
`go have()(...)` first `have()` part runs and the result is `fmt.Print("Go ")` and `return funWithGo`, then `fun("with Go.")` runs, and the result is `fmt.Print("have ")` and `return "with Go."`; now we have `go funWithGo("with Go.")`.

So the final **goroutine** call is `go funWithGo("with Go.")`
This is a call to start a new goroutine so really we don't know when it will run. So there is a chance for the next line to run: `fmt.Print("some ")`, then we wait here `wg.Wait()`. Now the goroutine runs this `funWithGo("with Go.")` and the result is `fmt.Println("fun", "with Go.")` then `wg.Done()`; that is all.

Let's rewrite the above code, just replace named functions with anonymous one, so this code is same as above:
For example see:

```
func have() func(string) {
    fmt.Print("Go ") // evaluation order: 1
    return funWithGo
}
```

And cut this code select the `have` part in the `go have()` and paste then select the `have` part in `func have()` and press `Delete` on the keyboard, then you'll have this:
[This](https://play.golang.org/p/RFiuFce-icI) is even more beautiful, with the same result, just replace all functions with anonymous functions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() func(string) {
        fmt.Print("Go ") // evaluation order: 1
        return func(msg string) {
            fmt.Println("fun", msg) // evaluation order: 4
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()(func(msg string) string {
        fmt.Print("have ") // evaluation order: 2
        return msg
    }("with Go."))

    fmt.Print("some ") // evaluation order: ~ 3
    wg.Wait()
}
```

---

Let me explain it with a simple example:
1. Consider this simple code:

```
i := 1
go fmt.Println(i) // 1
```

This is clear enough: the output is `1`.

But if the Go designers decided to evaluate the function argument at <s>the function run-time</s> nobody knows the value of `i`; you might change the `i` in your code (see the next example)

---

2. Now let's do this closure:

```
i := 1
go func() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(i) // ?
}()
```

The output is really **unknown**, and if the `main` goroutine exits sooner, it even won't have a chance to run: Wake up and print the `i`, which is `i` itself may change to that specific moment.

---

3. Now let's solve it like so:

```
i := 1
go func(i int) { 
    fmt.Printf("Step 3 i is: %d\n", i) // i = 1
}(i)
```

This anonymous function argument is of type `int` and it is a value type, and the value of `i` is known, and **the compiler-generated code** pushes the value `1` (`i`) to the stack, so this function, will use the value `1`, when the time comes (A time in the future).

---

4. All ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PbdXU_fQYrl)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    i := 1
    go fmt.Println(i) // 1 (when = unknown)
    go fmt.Println(2) // 2 (when = unknown)

    go func() { // closure
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(" This won't have a chance to run", i) // i = unknown  (when = unknown)
    }()

    i = 3
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Printf("Step 3 i is: %d\n", i) // i = 3 (when = unknown)
    }(i)

    i = 4

    go func(step int) { // closure
        fmt.Println(step, i) // i=? (when = unknown)
    }(5)
    i = 5
    fmt.Println(i) // i=5

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
5
5 5
2
1
Step 3 i is: 3
```

The Go Playground output:

```
5
5 5
1
2
Step 3 i is: 3
```

As you may be noticed, the order of `1` and `2` is random, and your output may differ (See the code comments).

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply, but I dont't understand [_this code_](https://play.golang.org/p/RFiuFce-icI) could you please explain the output ?

Comment: I understand the rewritten pattern, but I don't understand the output, the point is the output, not how to rewrite it. Like why that is the first evaluated, the why that is second, etc... Thanks in advance.

Comment: See **Explanation**, I hope this helps.