# Goroutine concept: direct call vs call using function literal

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

What are the basic differences between below two codes? Somehow, in the second example `demo_process2()` is never called but it works fine in the first example.

  1.

```golang
go func() {
    Must(demo_process1())
}()

demo_process2()
```

  2.

```golang
go Must(demo_process1())
demo_process2()
```

where `Must()`:

```golang
func Must(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: please show more of the output and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: See: [How go keyword works in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679714/8208215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spec: Go statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)

> **The function value and parameters are [evaluated as usual](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) in the calling goroutine**, but unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the function begins executing independently in a new goroutine.

In your first example you launch an anonymous function (a function literal) with no parameters as a new goroutine. `Must()` and `demo_process1()` are called inside that, *concurrently* with `demo_process2()` (which is executed in the "original" goroutine).

In your second example however:

```
go Must(demo_process1())
demo_process2()
```

The function launched as a goroutine is `Must()`, and its parameters are evaluated **in the calling goroutine**. Parameter of `Must()` is the return value of `demo_process1()`, which means `demo_process1()` is called and waited for first before a new goroutine is launched. Only when it returns may the new goroutine be started and `demo_process2()` be called (on the "original" goroutine).

All in all, in the second example `demo_process1()` and `demo_process2()` are not running concurrently but sequentially, in the same goroutine. Only the `Must()` is executed on a new goroutine (concurrently with `demo_process2()`).