# How does the defer keyword in Golang actually work

Tags: go

I had this code:

```
defer common.LogWarning(
    "b09ee123-f18b-46a8-b80d-f8361771178d:",
    resp.Body.Close(),  // gets called immediately, is *not* deferred..
)
```

and common.LogWarning is simply like this:

```
func LogWarning(uuid string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Warning(uuid, err)
    }
}
```

the problem is that `resp.Body.Close()` gets called immediately - that call is not deferred, so how does this work? Why is not the whole code block get deferred?

Comment: `"Why is not the whole code block get deferred"` because that's not a code block, you're calling `Close` to pass the returned error as an argument.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661114/8208215) helps.

Comment: Which part of defer's specification did you not understand? You are defering the call to common.LogWarning but of course all arguments are evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`defer` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) defers the function call.  The arguments to the function are evaluated immediately.

Use an anonymous function to accomplish your goal:

```
defer func() {
    common.LogWarning("b09ee123-f18b-46a8-b80d-f8361771178d:",
          resp.Body.Close())
}()
```

The call represented by the trailing `()` is deferred.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover):

> The behavior of defer statements is straightforward and predictable. There are three simple rules:
>
> 1. A deferred function's arguments are evaluated when the defer statement is evaluated.

Comment: so they are evaluated immediately

Comment: ...upon evaluation of the defer statement, yes.

Answer (score 2):

`defer` defers the execution of a function until the current function returns. The arguments to the function are evaluated immediately.

https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12

If you need to defer a code block where all evaluations are to be deferred, make it a function:

```
defer func() {
  // Stuff to defer here
}()
``
```