# Where is the second go routine in this piece of code as copied from gobyexample under channels

Tags: go

As explained on gobyexample https://gobyexample.com/channels, it says

**When we run the program the "ping" message is successfully passed from one goroutine to another via our channel.** but the way I see, its like we have only one go routine in the code, ie, `go func (text string) { messages <- "ping"}()` so I don't know from which go routine the "ping" message comes from and in which go routine it is put

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   messages := make(chan string)
   go func (text string) { messages <- "ping"}()

   msg := <-messages
   fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Comment: You can't _see_ goroutines. But the first one is initiated when `main()` is executed, and the second one is initiated with `go func...`.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid beginner question, @Richard. I'm not sure why it's being downvoted, and I hope it doesn't discourage you from using Stack Overflow. Here's a previous SO discussion which may provide more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388154/is-the-main-function-a-goroutine

Answer (score 0):

Go programs start with a single goroutine. Each `go` statement adds another. So, in your program, there are two: the one that started when `main()` started, and the one that the first started when it reached the line `go func ...`

```
func main() {
    messages := make(chan string) // goroutine 1
    go func (text string) {
        messages <- "ping"        // goroutine 2
    }()                           // goroutine 1 starting goroutine 2

    msg := <-messages             // goroutine 1
    fmt.Println(msg)              // goroutine 1
}
```

Comment: `()` requires a string to run eg. `("test")`.

Comment: @TomL I just explained the existing code, I did not modify it. Any errors are from the original code in the question.

Comment: OK, fair enough @Adrian.